# I want to be able to draw lines in codebehind for webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, drawing, html, code-behind

I'm looking at being able to draw lines in code behind in C#, for a webpage created in Visual Studio. They will be just vertical lines but must be able to change size, depending on other variables.

I've got some code, as below:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public partial class SpareFields : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap objBitmap;
        Graphics objGraphics;
        objBitmap = new Bitmap(400, 440);
        objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);
        objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 0);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(600, 1500, 601, 2000);
        objGraphics.DrawEllipse(p, rect);
        objBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
        //objBitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("x.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        objBitmap.Dispose();
        objGraphics.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And so on. This is just at the start of the `Page_Load` - there's a lot of other non-graphics code in there. Trouble is, the rest of the page is being ignored and it's just drawing the graphics.

Also, I know the above is for an Ellipse (basically a quick test on some pie chart drawing). It'd be easy to adapt for a line, or a really thin rectangle.

Any idea how to draw, whilst still having the rest of the original page available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just draw some lines I'd use [SVG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2010/03/21/getting-started-with-svg-an-example-driven-exploration-of-basic-svg-usage-in-xhtml.aspx), there are *very* [few reasons not to use it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) for dynamic images, the big huge advantage for svg is you can change the image on the page/client via JS.

*But* if you really want bitmaps, there are many articles around the web discussing Dynamic Image, a [Google for 'msdn dynamic image asp.net'](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=msdn+dynamic+image+asp.net&oq=msdn+dynamic+image+asp.net&gs_l=hp.3..35i39.1035.1035.0.2123.1.1.0.0.0.0.252.252.2-1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.HfbIW5754r0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44990110,d.d2k&fp=e45df0792d1f4b12&biw=1051&bih=868) should give you many, relevant articles with source.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to split this page in two:

1) your page outputs just it's html, including an `<img>` tag with a `src` attribute pointing to a new page
2) in that new page, use just that image generation code.

Comment: Hmm... there's no way to simply draw a line (or other object) either on top of the existing page or in a blank area of the page?

Comment: @user1560834 - you can't "just draw" on an html page. You need some sort of `<img>` element or a background image.

Comment: I guess this may make it easier to understand. I've got a lot of records (varies depending on what the user has specified) in a datalist. I want a blank column, as these are worksheets that the user will print and give to operatives to fill in dates that works have been complete. However, I don't think this can be done in the datalist itself (and it did have to be a datalist due to formatting) so I'm just trying to manually add a line to emulate a column.

Comment: @user1560834 - can't you add a blank column to your dataset, in that case? Or use a fixed image. Maybe you should start a new question with this requirement ("I need a printable form with blanks"), with some details, instead of focussing on a particular solution.

Comment: Good idea - will give that a go. I've marked both answers as "answered" as they'd work if I understood my question better.